# How can i make a menu centered?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="main-menu">

        <div class="main-menu-placeholder">
            <div class="main-menu-wrapper">
                <ul class="top-main-menu load-responsive" rel="Main Menu">
                    <li><a href="index.php">ANASAYFA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="detay.php">İÇİNDEKİLER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="detay.php">EDİTÖR</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Here is my codes what i asking about. i have tried everything to make it centered but i cant do it. is there any solution ?

Comment: do you mean the menu is vertical but centered with respect to the screen?

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us..

Comment: You need to write CSS...

Comment: I have css  and jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z3cuhq5n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/o3a8uucd/3/)

Here is a solution that centers it both vertically and horizontally, as you didn't mention how... The basic idea behind it is to place a div with `position:relative` into one positioned `absolute`

```
    .wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
        vertical-align:center;
    line-height:70px;
    height:70px;
    background:black;
}


.main-menu {
    position:relative;
    width:70%;
    background:#FE4C03;
    line-height:35px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
li,ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    margin:0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be a simple enough solution for you:

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper">

.main-menu-wrapper {
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes it can be a solution ty